# Group stream elements by weight function in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Imagine a

```
val myFlow: Flow[Element] = ... //some flow..
```

Given a weight function

```
val weightFunction: Element => Int
```

I would like to obtain a

```
val transformedFlow: Flow[List[Element]]
```

such that each element of the transformedFlow is a List[Element], such that the sum of the weights of the elements in that list is greater than a given constant.

How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `scan` to create a stream of accumulated weights, then `zip` the results with the original stream of elements and then use `splitAfter` to create substreams? I have not even tried to compile the following, but I hope you get the idea:

```
val broadCast = builder.add(Broadcast[Element](2))
val zip = builder.add(Zip[Element, Boolean])

myFlow.shape.out ~> broadCast.in

broadCast.out(0) ~> zip.in0

broadCast.out(1).scan(0){ (totalWeight, elem) =>
  if(totalWeight > Limit) weightFunction(elem)
  else totalWeight + weightFunction(elem)
}.map(_ > Limit) ~> zip.in1

val resultFlow =
  zip.out.splitAfter(_._2)
    .fold(List.empty[Element]){ case (list, (elem, _)) => elem :: list }
    .concatSubstreams
```

(You might want to consider doing `map(_.reverse)` on the resultFlow.)

Edit: you don't even need to do the `broadcast` and `zip` if you change the return type of the `scan` a bit - see a runnable code example here: https://gist.github.com/MartinHH/a05a87269b1697d5f57a1c77db269767